# Error in hadoop jobs due to hive query error

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, amazon-emr

Exception:

```
2017-06-21 22:47:49,993 FATAL ExecMapper (main): org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing writable org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBItemWritable@2e17578f
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:643)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:441)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:377)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while processing record: org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBItemWritable@2e17578f
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBObjectInspector.getColumnData(DynamoDBObjectInspector.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBObjectInspector.getStructFieldData(DynamoDBObjectInspector.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspectorConverters$StructConverter.convert(ObjectInspectorConverters.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:626)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "17664956244983174066"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:444)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:483)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBDataParser.getNumberObject(DynamoDBDataParser.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.type.HiveDynamoDBNumberType.getHiveData(HiveDynamoDBNumberType.java:28)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBObjectInspector.getColumnData(DynamoDBObjectInspector.java:128)
    ... 12 more
```

The hive query I am sending is:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE temp_1 
         SELECT * FROM temp_2 
         WHERE t_id="17664956244983174066" and t_ts="636214684577250000000";
```

Is this number too big to be converted to int? I even tried sending `17664956244983174066` without quotes but i get the same exception.

`t_id` is defined as `BIGINT` in `hive table` and `N` or Number in dynamobd

EDIT:

I tried by defining `t_id` as `string` ==> `Schema mismatch as dynamodb stores this as int`

`t_id` as `double` ==>> `precision lost. no match.`

What can be the solution here?

Comment: What are the data types of `t_id` and `t_ts`?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz BIGINT in Hive..........Number in dynamodb

Comment: @WestonE any ideas???????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution from AWS experts is to

1. git clone open source emr-dynamodb-connector
2. modify the code
3. prepare your own Jar
4. Using bootstrapper upload it to EMR
5. In run_job_flow , send configurations for `hadoop env` appending your own location of jars in `HADOOP_CLASSPATH`.

Being not so much into Java, modifying emr-dynamodb-connector was not possible for me, but this is the solution. Also two things can be done... if you don't use `Strings` in Dynamodb, map `string` of `hive` to `number` of Dynamodb, else add mapping and support for `decimal` from hive to Dynamodb `number`

Answer (score 2):

> Is this number too big to be converted to int?

Yes, this number is too big to convert to an integral type.  According to the Apache Hive documentation on [Numeric Types](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-NumericTypes), the maximum value for a `BIGINT` is 9223372036854775807.  Your input, 17664956244983174066, is larger than that.

The following is a vanilla Hive query (no DynamoDB integration) demonstrating the effects of attempting to convert various inputs to a `BIGINT`.

```
SELECT
    "9223372036854775807" AS str,
    cast("9223372036854775807" AS BIGINT) AS numbigint,
    cast("9223372036854775807" AS DOUBLE) AS numdouble
UNION ALL
SELECT
    "9223372036854775808" AS str,
    cast("9223372036854775808" AS BIGINT) AS numbigint,
    cast("9223372036854775808" AS DOUBLE) AS numdouble
UNION ALL
SELECT
    "17664956244983174066" AS str,
    cast("17664956244983174066" AS BIGINT) AS numbigint,
    cast("17664956244983174066" AS DOUBLE) AS numdouble
;

    str numbigint   numdouble
0   9223372036854775807 9223372036854775807 9.2233720368547758e+18
1   9223372036854775808 NULL    9.2233720368547758e+18
2   17664956244983174066    NULL    1.7664956244983173e+19
```

At the documented maximum value of `BIGINT`, the value converts correctly.  At just 1 higher, the conversion fails, resulting in `NULL`.  The same thing happens for your input.

The query also demonstrates that conversion to `DOUBLE` is successful.  Perhaps that's a solution, depending on your use case.  Compared to an integral data type, this would open a risk of encountering floating point precision issues.

From your stack trace, it appears that the DynamoDB integration results in a `NumberFormatException` for this case rather than `NULL`. This is arguably a bug in the DynamoDB connector, but even if it were changed to map to `NULL`, you still wouldn't have a successful conversion.

Comment: With double it gets converted to `1.7664956244983173e+19` and search result becomes 0.Any other way or options

Comment: @vks , I wasn't sure what you meant by "search result becomes 0".  Does this imply you need to do an equality match on the value?  If so, then is it acceptable to switch to a fuzzier match on the decimal value, like `WHERE value BETWEEN X AND Y`?  Unfortunately, I don't have further advice on working with an integer value wider than 8 bytes in a Hive query.  Is it possible to prevent such large values in the source data?

Comment: No cant prevent large values :(

Comment: @vks , no worries!  Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 1):

Your numbers are out of range for bigint.
Define everything as a string in both sides.

Comment: I cannot do that...:( ... Cannot change the tables

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hive/hive_data_types.htm ,  the DECIMAL type will work for you.

> The DECIMAL type in Hive is as same as Big Decimal format of Java. It is used for representing immutable arbitrary precision. The syntax and example is as follows:

```
DECIMAL(precision, scale)
decimal(10,0)
```

Comment: But Amazon EMR dynamodb connector does not accept decimal datatype

Comment: Ders an open feature request on it too on git for this

Answer (score 1):

I have not used EMR but here goes my guess :)

Hive automatically try to transform your input because your target field is a BigInt, did you try something like this?

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE temp_1 
SELECT * FROM temp_2 
WHERE cast(t_id as string)="17664956244983174066" and cast(t_ts as string)="636214684577250000000";
```

Based on my experience this should avoid the casting of your input, however you could get exceptions inserting in the new table, you can cast your fields during the select, if you have too many columns you can also try this

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/7703/whether-hive-supports-hive-select-all-query-with-e.html

Comment: That doesnt work as it gets converted to double...check emr-dynamodb-connector code....so it looses precision